# I want to include the tex file because it contains the information about citation. But I don't want to print that tex file in my pdf

Tags: pdftex

\begin{document}
\include{ref}
\printbibliography[title= References]
\end{document}

I don't want to print the ref.tex file in my pdf but I want to keep information inside it

Comment: You should rather use biblatex and a .bib file. I don't get what is in your ref.tex file.

Comment: A bit hard to tell not knowing what's in file `ref`, but you could try "typesetting" it inside a box that's never actually used: `\setbox0=\hbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\include{ref}}}`.

Comment: \setbox0=\hbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\include{ref}}} worked for me. Thank you for the suggestion.